# reload systemd-networkd without a reboot?

Tags: networking, configuration, systemd

Is it possible to reload changes in `/etc/systemd/network/*` in a live system?

already tried `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service`, `networkctl`... nothing seems to avoid a full reboot.

Answer (score 3):

confirmed `systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `networkctl reload` works on 249

i can see the changes on `journalctl -xeu systemd-networkd`

it will only reload/re-apply changes in  `.network` and `.netdev` file. And **not** for `.link` etc.